# Java Duplicate class protobuf

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I have tried to exclude but nothing works and I'm stuck. It seems like I have dependency issues.

Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Writer$FieldOrder found in modules protobuf-java-3.21.9 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.21.9) and protobuf-javalite-3.21.7 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.21.7)

build gradle app

```
 plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
    
    
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    android {
        compileSdk 33
    
    
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.nauka"
            minSdk 31
            targetSdk 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'google/protobuf/*.proto'
        }
    
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'protobuf.meta'
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
    
    
        implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0'
        implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.32'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
        implementation 'org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4'
        implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.6.1'
    
        implementation ('com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.21.9') {
            exclude module: 'protobuf-javalite'
        }
        implementation ('com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.21.7') {
            exclude module: 'protobuf-java'
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    }
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.5'

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```